# Adding only one value to the table in sql

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table named `student` which consists of (`rollno, name, sem, branch`)

If I want to `INSERT` only one value (i.e only name has to be entered) what is the query?

Answer (score 23):

To insert values into specific columns, you first have to specify which columns you want to populate.  The query would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO your_table_name (your_column_name)
VALUES (the_value);
```

To insert values into more than one column, separate the column names with a comma and insert the values in the same order you added the column names:

```
INSERT INTO your_table_name (your_column_name_01, your_column_name_02)
VALUES (the_value_01, the_value_02);
```

If you are unsure, have a look at W3Schools.com.  They usually have explanations with examples.

Answer (score 7):

```
insert into student(name) values("The name you wan to insert");
```

Be careful not to forget to insert the primary key.

Comment: if the primary key column was an auto-incrementing int, you would not want to insert it

Answer (score 6):

First, if the table is all empty, just wanna make the column 'name' with values, it is easy to use INSERT INTO. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp.

```
`INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (COLUMN_NAME) VALUES ("the values")`
```

Second, if the table is already with some values inside, and only wanna insert some values for one column, use UPDATE. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

```
  UPDATE table_name SET column1 = value1 WHERE condition;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into student (name)
select 'some name'
```

or

```
insert into student (name)
values ('some name')
```

Answer (score 2):

Following works if other columns accept null or do have default value:

```
INSERT INTO Student (name) VALUES('Jack');
```

Further details can be found from the [Reference Manual:: 13.2.5 INSERT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html).

Answer (score 0):

Execute this query, if you want the rest of columns as `"#"`, do insert `#` inside the single quote which is left blank in query.

Also, there is no need of defining column name in the query.

```sql
insert into student values('','your name','','');
```

Thanks...

Comment: Here, `student` is the table and no columns are specified, so all columns `(rollno, name, sem, branch)` are taken over from the table. The order of the values is important.